# About "move to"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, prepositional-phrases

Is it correct to use "move to" in the following context?

I will stay in Gozo for a few days then move to Malta island for the rest of my stay in Malta.

I plan to stay in Malta only for 12 days but not really to live there.

Or, "move to" always means "to go from one place of residence to another"?

If this is wrong, how can I express it correctly in English?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: The fact that you mention "the rest of my stay" makes it clear that you are talking about a holiday and not about moving house. However, you could use other terms such as "transfer to" or "cross over to".

Comment: ah so move to only means "the relocation of your residence".  I thought it could be used just for physical transfer to another place.  I understand now.  Thank you!

Comment: I did _not_ say that "move to" _only_ referred to changing residences! I said that the context of your sentence makes it clear that you were not moving house, but you could describe the move in other ways.